# How to find out which message causes exception in writting by Netty?

Tags: java, tcp, exception, netty, tcpclient

There is a Java TCP-Client connected to a Server using `Netty`.
Writing in a disconnected channel causes exception. It's not important which problem is causing this, but it's important to me which message was **not sent** and caused the exception.

How to find it [by using ChannelPromise or ChannelFuture]?

here I just get '`f.isSuccess()==true`', but it's not success! message was not sent!

```
ChannelPromise promise = c.newPromise();
            promise.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture f) {
                    System.err.println("<TCPIn: promise write operationComplete.");
                    if (!f.isSuccess()) {
                        System.err.println("<TCPIn[writting]: promise write ERROR:");
                        f.cause().printStackTrace();
                        f.channel().close();
                    }
                }
            });
channel.writeAndFlush(buf,promise);
```

Comment: Can't you access your buf object from the listener itself? This would work in most cases, but not in the cases EJP says in his answer

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that simple. What caused the exception was failure to receive acknowledgment for a segment transmitted from the socket send buffer. Correlation with a specific message may be zero. It could have been half of one message and half of the next, for example, and it will certainly have been data from a prior write rather than the one just completed. Remember that 'write completion' in TCP means nothing more than successful buffering of the data in the socket send buffer.

Comment: OK, your'e right. so how to find out whether the message was sent completely or not? I just want to know if the message was sent successfully.

Comment: The only way to really be ensure that something was successfully received in TCP is send back an "ACK message". This will be part of your protocol itself and would be build on top of TCP.

Comment: @NormanMaurer I don't want to know about receiving messages, I just want to know if a message has been sent successfully or not.

Comment: @NormanMaurer Also sending ACKs is depended on the server. I'm just a client.

Comment: There is no way when using TCP... You will need to build some kind of logic into your protocol that uses TCP.